# Engen problems with a golf mk2

Tags: golf

I drive a vw golf mk2. The engen idles fine when standing,but as soon as I put it in gear and want to drive,the engen want to die. But out of gear,the engen seems fine. I can pull away while on choke,but as soon as I turn it off again,the car looses power. I suspected that the plug cables need replacement for a couple of weeks as the idling got stange and seems that the engen lost power. What should I look for?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Mk2? Manual or auto tranny?